# How to solve problem correlation calculation with DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]I am trying to build a measure with the correlation coefficient in power bi (DAX), to see how the tests performed by collaborators are related, I have 159 columns that represent each test, I am overriding the dynamization of columns to solve the problem but I understand that it is a calculation with two variables X and Y, how do I solve this problem when I have 159 columns?

The R corrplot (Power BI) does not help me because when filtering by PersonID the graph does not generate visual me, as there is a significant reduction in the records.

So far I have managed to construct the measure of covariance and correlation but without the expected results.

Example DAX

```html
    Covarianza = 
     VAR CONTEO = COUNTROWS('public SabanaDatos')
     VAR AVG1 = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('public SabanaDatos'[Valor]),REMOVEFILTERS('public SabanaDatos'[Atributo]))
     VAR AVG2 = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('public SabanaDatos'[Valor]),REMOVEFILTERS('public SabanaDatos'[Atributo]))
     VAR TABLA =
     ADDCOLUMNS(
         'public SabanaDatos',
         "Covarianza",
         DIVIDE(
             (CALCULATE(AVERAGE('public SabanaDatos'[Valor]),REMOVEFILTERS('public SabanaDatos'[Atributo]))-AVG1)*
             (CALCULATE(AVERAGE('public SabanaDatos'[Valor]),REMOVEFILTERS('public SabanaDatos'[Atributo]))-AVG2),
             CONTEO))
    RETURN
        SUMX(TABLA,[Covarianza])

Coef_Corr_1 = 
     DIVIDE([Covarianza],
     STDEV.P('public SabanaDatos'[Var_X])*
     CALCULATE(STDEV.P('public SabanaDatos'[Valor]),REMOVEFILTERS('public SabanaDatos'[Atributo])),
     0)
```

[image]

Comment: I'd strongly recommend unpivoting your columns so that you have just a handful rather than 159 .

Comment: Yes, column dynamization was column. Leave a picture of how it looks.